# Is it possible to specify a data type in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I'd like to initiliaze a matrix in R and I know all its values are going to be between 0 and 255.

Is it a way to take advantage of this by specifying a datatype like `int8` .

For instance in Python and Numpy I can easily do that with `dtype=int8` .

Comment: You can initialize a matrix like this: `matrix(data=NA_integer_, nrow=10, ncol=10)` vs `NA_real_`, `NA_character_`, etc, but what are you hoping to gain (I'm assuming memory)?

Comment: Yes I'd like to do that for memory purpose, but I'm not sure to understand your proposal,  I don't want an integer type but a small integer type.

Comment: R doesn't easily allow you to use small integer types (integers are 4 bytes, that's it). (in Python you would need `uint8`, for what it's worth)

Comment: So if I understand well, this is not possible to optimise a matrix memory usage in R. At least not as much as Numpy.

Comment: yes, I would say that.  Although R does have good support for *sparse* matrices.